# vue redirect with props

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

```
  path: '/shop/products/:products',
  props: true,
  redirect: '/',
  component: Example
```

I need to access the `props` in my component which works fine without redirect but when `redirect` is added the props are `undefined` in my component. Any inputs why I can not access my props.

Comment: What props are you passing? Are they undefined for just the `'/'` route or both?

Comment: the props being passed are `products`, yes they are defined for both the routes. The `props` are `undefined` when used with `redirect`

Answer (score 0):

Do you register the props in your component?

```
<script>
    export default {
        props: ['products'],
    };
</script>
```

in order to test add the below inside script:

```
    mounted() {
        if (this.products){
            console.log(this.products, 'products')
           
        }
    },
```

About the undefined issue that you get is because in the redirect url there is not any :products route param.

If i were you i would delete the redirect from router file and when i need to redirect i would add in the vue component the below:

```
            this.$router.push('/');
```